# How to compile the pgfmanual with mlmodern fonts?

Tags: tikz-pgf, fonts, documentation, mlmodern

I simply want a version of the pgf/Ti*k*Z manual with the bolder `mlmodern` fonts instead of the original `lm` fonts. To achieve this, I cloned the pgf repo from git, loaded the `mlmodern` package after the `amsmath` and `amssymb` packages in the `pgfmanual-en-main-preamble.tex` file and compiled it on an updated (today) version of `TeX Live` using `l3build doc -q -H`. The `amsmath` and `amssymb` packages were already loaded in the code. It compiled for a very long time and generated a pdf, but I don't see the `mlmodern` fonts in the pdf. The compiled pdf is not correct as well; I don't find the monospaced font used for the code. I can share the log files if needed.

How do I replace the lm fonts with the mlmodern fonts in the PGF manual?

Comment: Can you share what changes you made to the manual source to use `mlmodern`? Or if you used the map substitution method? Is the monospace font absent even without changes?

Comment: @tsj Ah, sorry. In forgot to tell what I did. I loaded `mlmodern` along with `amssymb` and `amsmath`.

Comment: Which compiler did you use? Which file did you add the package into? What's in the log file regarding fonts?

Comment: Note that the `.cfg` indicates (the unmodified version of) the manual should be compiled with LuaTeX and this modifies the loading of the monospaced family.

Comment: @cfr
 I used `l3build doc -q -H`. That is the build recipe as suggested on the github page. It uses lualatex. I added the package to the `pgfmanual-en-main-preamble.tex` file.

Comment: So remove the `-q` to see what's happening.

Comment: @cfr I just recompiled without `-q`. I added `\usepackage{mlmodern}` after `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` (both times) in the preamble document. I removed all the files in the `pgfmanual-en-main-body.tex`, except `pgfmanual-en-main-body`, to speed up the compilation. I did not load `mlmodern` when loading `amsfonts`.

Comment: How do I see what is happening as a result of removing the `-q` option? I have the log file

Comment: @cfr I can use other open type fonts, such as newcm if using mlmodern with lualatex is a problem. I don't have any problem with the default latin modern monospace font, just the roman text font.

Comment: Instead of using `mlmodern`, I simply added `usepackage{fontsetup}` at the end of the preamble file. It compile successfully when only the introduction is included. The compilation fails for some reason when one tries to compile the whole manual.

Comment: Worked fine for me (`mlmodern` fonts rendered successfully) by adding `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` and `\usepackage{mlmodern}` on line 181 of `pgfmanual-en-main-manual.tex`. Normally `fontenc` won't get loaded if you consider what happens with the `if` blocks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Force the use of `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` to make `mlmodern` work with LuaTeX.

From lines 158 -- 180 of `pgfmanual-en-main-preamble.tex` as it appears in the pgf GitHub repository currently,

```latex
\ifluatex
%  \usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
%  \usepackage{luatextra}

  % TT: I have commented luatextra since it loads fontspec, which
  % currently breaks "$\mathrm{\Omega}$" (nothing is
  % shown). Also, fontspec loads so much stuff, I'm not really sure
  % any of it is needed...

  % \filedescription is defined in expl3, required by fontspec,
  % required by luatextra. Needs to be \relaxed since
  % pgfmanual-en-macros.tex defines an environment named filedescription
  \let\filedescription\relax
  \usepackage[utf8]{luainputenc}
  % dvisvgm does not support OpenType fonts so we have to bite the bullet and
  % use T1 where quotes are weird.  In LuaTeX \outputmode=0 means DVI.
  \ifnum\outputmode=0
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
  \fi
\else
  \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\fi
```

The manual build uses `lualatex` by default. So we enter the first branch of the conditional. Comments indicate that `LuaTeX \outputmode=0 means DVI`, and `lualatex` ordinarily generates a PDF, so we skip the `\ifnum` conditional, and `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` is never inserted, but it is required for `mlmodern` to work in LuaTeX. So, you can add

```latex
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mlmodern}
```

after the outer `\iflatex ... \else ... \fi` block above. Comments also suggest `quotes are weird` for `T1` with LuaTeX. I don't have much experience with LuaTeX, but compiling in this way, I don't see anything wrong with ordinary ``` ``quotations'' ```, and don't find any glaring artifacts after scanning through the manual.