# Compiling the PGF/TikZ manual with other fonts:  (U+03A9) and  (U+1D707) in the circuit libraries

Tags: tikz-pgf, fonts, table-of-contents, compiling, documentation

I wish to have the PGF/Ti*k*Z manual with a different font. I find the default Latin Modern too spindly. Thus, I have tried to compile the manual with the MLModern and New Computer Modern (NCM) fonts. I have asked compiling the manual with the MLModern fonts in [an other question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/692958/128462). Since it is recommended to compile the manual with LuaLaTeX, and NCM fonts are OpenType, my guess is that it should be easier to compile with them as compared to the MLModern ones. I have tried the following.

1. I have cloned the [PGF repository](https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf) from GitHub using `git clone https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf`.
2. I added `\usepackage{fontsetup}` at the end of the `pgfmanual-en-main-preamble.tex` file.
3. Compiled the manual with `l3build doc -H`. I did not do any of the `usertreee` business. I am using an updated version of TeX Live 2023.

The compilation goes for a very long time and generates a pdf with the correct fonts, but without the table of contents and reference hyperlinks. It outputs a message that the **compilation failed**, but I cannot find any errors in the `pgfmanual.log` file. The compilation goes fine if I compile only till part 3 'TikZ ist kein Zeichenprogramm'. The manual compiles correctly without any problems if I don't load `fontsetup`.

What have fonts got to do with generating the toc and bookmarks? Why aren't there any errors in the `.log` file? The `.log` file can be found here: https://pastebin.com/L7MnKDxi.

---

EDIT:

I think I have identified the problem. The log shows that

`Missing character: There is no  (U+1D6FA) in font [NewCM10-Book.otf]:mode=ba se;script=latn;language=dflt;!`

and

`Missing character: There is no  (U+1D707) in font [NewCM10-Book.otf]:mode=ba se;script=latn;language=dflt;!`.

This happens due to the 'Circuit Libraries' section (`pgfmanual-en-library-circuits`). Removing that section while compiling gives correct results. I don't understand the errors though.

Why are the above mentioned characters expected in NewCM *text* fonts?
They belong to the Unicode math block and are indeed present in the NCM Math font. Also,  (U+1D6FA) is Mathematical Italic Capital Omega and  (U+1D707) is Mathematical Italic Small Mu. Why are they italic? By this, I mean why does the circuit library these italic characters? And that too from the text, and not the math font? Why does not this give an error with the default LM fonts? In the resulting (default) pdf, I find that the characters are upright in appearance, as they should be. But searching  in the resulting pdf in Okular surprisingly matches the upright uppercase Omega in the pdf. Why is this the case? But when I copy the upright uppercase Omega from the pdf and paste it [here](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+03A9), I get Greek Capital Letter Omega (U+03A9). I don't understand this. Also, this character is present in the NewCM text fonts.

Unicode has Ω (U+2126) Ohm Sign and µ (U+00B5) Micro Sign specified as well. Shouldn't they be invoked instead? Both are availabe in the NCM fonts.  As a real effect of this selection, the µ (U+00B5) Micro Sign has the appearance of an upright mu, with a serif at the bottom, while the micro sign in the default LM pdf is an italic mu.

Comment: the missing char messages are only warnings, they should let the compilation fail (and it didn't fail according to your log), you get them as fontsetup loads unicode-math, while the pdfmanual uses the legacy math fonts.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer The compilation failed--that is what the log says at the end.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Also, does this mean the circuit library is incompatible with unicode-math?

Comment: I didn't look, but probably one would only have to adapt the macros used for the two symbols.

Comment: The manual sets `\tracinglostchars=3` in its preamble which makes it error when encountering missing glyphs.

Comment: @JasperHabicht Thanks. Removing `\tracinglostchars=3` along with `amsfonts` and `amssymb` removes any errors and the document compiles fine. I have removed `amsfonts` and `amssymb` under the assumption that they are not needed with `unicode-math`. Still, I don't understand why it gives the warnings of missing characters. Why are the characters expected in the first place?

Comment: To avoid the missing chars you can replace `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`  by `\PassOptionsToPackage{mathrm=sym}{unicode-math} \usepackage{fontsetup}`. (the comment there also mentiones that there is a problem with `\mathrm{\Omega}`).